# Regex to Trim a String inside JSON

Tags: regex, kibana

I have the following log message inside LogZ and I'd like to trim it before forwarding it as an alarm:

```
[ {
 "message" : "{\"level\":\"error\",\"msg\":\"Unexpected error! Contact the administrator!\",\"reason\":\"Error while unmarshalling the incoming data. Likely due to formats mismatch\",\"status\":\"500\",\"success\":false,\"time\":\"2022-02-15T18:47:08Z\"}\n"
}, {
 "message" : "{\"level\":\"error\",\"msg\":\"Unexpected error! Contact the administrator!\",\"reason\":\"Error while unmarshalling the incoming data. Likely due to formats mismatch\",\"status\":\"500\",\"success\":false,\"time\":\"2022-02-15T18:47:06Z\"}\n"
}, {
 "message" : "{\"level\":\"error\",\"msg\":\"Unexpected error! Contact the administrator!\",\"reason\":\"Error while unmarshalling the incoming data. Likely due to formats mismatch\",\"status\":\"500\",\"success\":false,\"time\":\"2022-02-15T18:47:05Z\"}\n"
} ]
```

Since LogZ (Kibana) supports Regex, the main idea was to remove everything besides the `reason` field with the message it carries. So is there anyway I can use regex to end with the following message?:

`reason: Error while unmarshalling the incoming data. Likely due to formats mismatch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it using `positive look behind` from string `reason\":\"` and extract all character behind it until `\`.

Here the example : https://regex101.com/r/14otax/1

```
(?<=reason\\":\\")[^\\]+
```

[image: example regex]